# What could generate this expensive MySql query in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm having troubles identifying the cause of high mysql usage. I see a lot of such queries in "Sending Data" state, using SHOW PROCESSLIST and was, so far, unable to find what generates these queries.

Context is a high traffic Wordpress powered news site.

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE 
    `meta_key` = '_wp_attached_file' 
    AND LOWER(`meta_value`) IN 
        ("...long-list-of-files-here...") LIMIT 76
```

Comment: Maybe the fileexplorer in the WP-Backend cause this query?

Comment: Nope. It's not related to that.